# If it possible to move cursor to new line (like skype "Alt+Enter")

Tags: lync

In Lync, is it possible to move cursor to a new line when writing message (like Skype's <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>)?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Yes you can, try the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> key combination.

Comment: `shift + enter` is the way, just like with all other textareas which auto-submit on enter (like Stackoverflow, Facebook, etc). `alt + enter` is usually the fullscreen shortcut.

Comment: Could be useful for someone else:  [All IM shortcuts](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Keyboard-shortcuts-for-Skype-for-Business-74eda765-5631-4fc1-8aad-cc870115347a#__toc327975868)